# Can't edit Bootstrap Carousel js

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, slider, carousel

I'm trying to edit the interval for the slider with a .carousel script within the html but it doesn't seem to be working. I am also trying to edit the carousel to achieve something like this:

[image: http://www.responsivejqueryslider.com/preview_images/SweetIcon.jpg]

but I can't seem to find what to edit and what to edit it with.

Here's code

> ```
> <div class="text-center container-final">
> <div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel" style="border-radius:25px !important; overflow:hidden !important; background-color:#2a2a2a !important;">
>     <ol class="carousel-indicators">
>         <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
>         <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
>         <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
>     </ol>
>     <div class="carousel-inner" style="overflow:hidden; background-color:#2a2a2a;">
>         <div class="item active" style="border:3px solid #d9534f; border-radius:25px; overflow:hidden; background-color:#2a2a2a;">
>             <img src="images/img001.jpg" alt="Img1" class="img-responsive">
>             <div class="carousel-caption">
>                 <a class="btn btn-game1">Game1</a>
>             </div>
>         </div>
>         <div class="item" style="border:3px solid #5cb85c; border-radius:25px; overflow:hidden; background-color:#2a2a2a;">
>             <img src="images/img002.jpg" alt="Img2" class="img-responsive">
>             <div class="carousel-caption">
>                 <a class="btn btn-game2">Game2</a>
>             </div>
>         </div>
>         <div class="item" style="border:3px solid #f0ad4e; border-radius:25px; overflow:hidden; background-color:#2a2a2a;">
>             <img src="images/img003.jpg" alt="Img3" class="img-responsive">
>             <div class="carousel-caption">
>                 <a class="btn btn-game3">Game3</a>
>             </div>
>         </div>
>     </div>
>     <a class="carousel-control left" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="prev" style=" overflow:hidden;">
>         <span class="icon-prev">&lsaquo;</span>
>     </a>
>     <a class="carousel-control right" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="next" style=" overflow:hidden;">
>         <span class="icon-next">&rsaquo;</span>
>     </a>
> </div>
> </div>
> ```
>
> $('#myCarousel').carousel({
>         interval: 9000
>       });

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways to set interval for slider, one is

**Data Attributes method**:   (Mention data-interval at your carousel slide div)

```
<div class="text-center container-final">
<div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel" data-interval="9000">
--
--
</div>
</div>
```

Oher method is with **javascript**:
Add following script at end of your HTML file:

```
<script>
    $('#myCarousel').carousel({
        interval: 9000
    })
</script>
```

Comment: I tried the script at the end of the file and it doesn't seem to change the interval time.

Comment: Yeah, I just tried it now, and it seem so work with the first one